# two digit number multiplication problem

Tags: contest-math, products

> $77$  is  multiplied  by  another two-digit   number  with    identical   digits. The third
>   digit   of  the product,    counting    from    left    to  right,  is  a   $3$. What    is  the product?

I just guessed $55$ and it turned out to yield the right answer ($4235$), but I was wondering if there was a more mathematical way to this. I actually did put the two-digit number as $(10a+a) = 11a$, which gave me $847a$, but without knowing how many digits there are in total in the product, how can I carry on from there?

Comment: i think $$77\cdot 44=3388$$ is also one solution

Comment: ok this is not true

Comment: $$77\cdot 55=4235$$ is the only solution.

Comment: Since a perfect square can't end in $3$, you can eliminate the cases where the product is $3$-digits.

Answer (score 2):

From $847*a$, we get that the one's digit will be $7*a \mod 10$ which is congruent to $3$ only if $a = 9$, which would lead to a $4$-digit number with $3$ as the last and fourth digit. Therefore, your number must be 4 digits. The third digit, then, is $\frac{7*a - (7*a \mod 10)}{10} + (4*a \mod 10)= 3$

$$\frac{7*a - (7*a \mod 10)}{10} + (4*a \mod 10)= 3$$
$${7*a - (7*a \mod 10)} + (40*a \mod 10)= 30$$
$$7*a - (7*a \mod 10) = 30$$

Clearly, $5$ is the only solution.

Comment: I don't quite understand how a=9 and leading to a 4-digit number necessarily tells me that it needs to be a 4-digit number for other values of a as well...

Comment: There are two conditions that must be met: $7*a \equiv 3 \mod 10$ and $847 \cdot a$ is three digits. First, we look at all the possible values that satisfy the first condition. None of those values satisfy the second, so it cannot be three digits.